# GCP: install mod_headers

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform

It seems my server setup does not support headers in .htaccess

When I try to add this below code in .htaccess file, My site breaks.

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
</filesMatch>
```

So my question is how do I install *mod_headers* in the GCP where my apache server is.

For the httpd.conf file: following is the tutorial

https://www.onepagezen.com/add-expires-headers-wordpress-bitnami/

But my server uses apache2.conf file instead of the httpd.conf

Can't find the solution, any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Man, I've had the same issue.

First off, next time you setup a wordpress via GCP, try out KUSANAGI OS, incredibly fast.

You need to make sure you put the FilesMatch config in the right spot.

httpd/apache2 and the way they load conf seems to be rather complex, so I can't provide a specific reason as why it doesn't work when you place it.

BUT!

according to: https://serverfault.com/questions/648262/filesmatch-configuration-to-restrict-file-extensions-served

you might have a chance by trying to place it in v_host.conf, as per:

```
The FilesMatch directive is applied against the "directory" hit prior to the mod-dir 
DirectoryIndex directive assignment to "index.htm." As a result, a "null" condition 
must pass the test in order for the request to be handled. With that, this set up 
(all the same except for this change to the V_HOST.conf file) works:...
```